# Compressed files using php won't work in windows

Tags: php, compression

I am trying to compress some video files on the fly using php and forcing compressed file to download. Below is the code I have written.

```
$files_todownload_string = ' movie1.mov movie2.mov '

header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' ); 

$fp = popen('zip -v - ' . $files_todownload_string, 'r');
$bufsize = 8192;
$buff = '';
while( !feof($fp) ) {
$buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
echo $buff;
print "
";
}
pclose($fp);
```

The compression is done perfectly and the zip file is downloaded successfully. However, when I am trying to open the zip file in windows os, it won't open. It says that the compressed file is corrupted.

Any helps guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. The zipped files are working in all OS Linux, Windows and Mac.

Below is code:

```
$files_array = array();
$files_array[] = 'file1.mov';
$files_array[] = 'file2.mov';
$file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
foreach($files_array as $k => $v) {
$zip->addFile( $path.$files_available[$v] );
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' ); 
ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);
```

Thanks everybody for giving the time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `print "
";`

You're adding extra bytes.

Comment: Tried removing the print "
"; already but the result is same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're setting the file type as gzip. Maybe try a zip type.

Comment: Lastly, is the zip file zipped by the time the server sends it to browser? What if you use the php zip functions and wait for the file to be zipped?

Comment: Setting the file type as gzip is not a problem as I can download and unzip the file successfully in linux but failed in windows. Also the there are no issues with the time delay during the zipping process.